# From which you have received (it)

Tags: writing-style, objects

Consider the following sentence:

> Please return the box back to the address from which you have received **it**.

Is the last **it** absolutely necessary? If not, what is the recommended style? Google seems to return both instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the last *it* is necessary for the sentence to make grammatical sense.

*Receive*, when applied to specific objects (like the box), is transitive, so it needs an object to be acted upon.  You receive the box; "the box" is nicknamed *it* (for the purposes of this sentence; this is called [anaphora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_%28linguistics%29)), hence you receive *it*.

That said, it sounds much better to me to reword it:

> Please return the box to the address it came from.

Comment: Right. _Which_ refers to _the address_, so it can't refer to _the box_. And _receive_ does not allow its object to be deleted (or "understood").

Comment: *Back* and *which* are superfluous and (I think) unnatural in that rewording; I think "Please return the box to the address it came from" is significantly better.

Comment: @jwpat7 Yup, edited.